# Get HTML input into Google sheet in a specific format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The code snippet below is part of a larger script that collects user input from an HTML file and store these user input into my Google sheet. The type of input fields from the line
`formObject.firmenp` all the way to the line `formObject.zielplanung` in my HTML file is date and have each their own specific ID. I want to get these dates in format **day/month/year** into my sheet.

Any idea or recommendation how to achieve that?

Thank you so much in advance for your help :).

```
function getFormValues(formObject){
  if(formObject.RecId && checkID(formObject.RecId)){
    var values = [[formObject.RecId.toString(),
    formObject.name,
    formObject.unternehmen,
    formObject.rufnummer,
    formObject.email,
    formObject.firmenp,
    formObject.onboarding,
    formObject.selbsttraining,
    formObject.crmm,
    formObject.tblock1,
    formObject.fdtblock,
    formObject.wochentraining,
    formObject.zielplanung,
    formObject.changestatus]];
  }else{
    var values = [[new Date().getTime().toString(),
    formObject.name,
    formObject.unternehmen,
    formObject.rufnummer,
    formObject.email,
    formObject.firmenp,
    formObject.onboarding,
    formObject.selbsttraining,
    formObject.crmm,
    formObject.tblock1,
    formObject.fdtblock,
    formObject.wochentraining,
    formObject.zielplanung,
    formObject.changestatus]];
  }
  return values;
}
```

Comment: just to be clear, what types of values you are getting?

Comment: @TBA - Yeah, these input are being collected from the html page and stored into the google sheet without any issue. But I want them to be stored in my google sheet in format day/month/year. And that´s where I am kind of stuck :(

Comment: @TBA - I am getting this kind of format/values: "2021-11-05". So, year/month/day. But I want DAY/MONTH/YEAR. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function like the below and convert all your data using it. Use this function on your script page.

```js
//2021-11-05


var getDate = document.getElementById("date").value;
console.log("Inputted data: " + getDate);

function getNewDateFormat(value){
  var dateValue = new Date(value);
  var monthPart = dateValue.getMonth() + 1;
  var dayPart = dateValue.getDate();
  var yearPart = dateValue.getFullYear();
  
  var newFormat = dayPart + "/" + monthPart + "/" + yearPart;
  
  return newFormat
}

console.log("Expected data: " + getNewDateFormat(getDate));
```

```html
//dummy input 
<input type="text" id="date" value="2021-11-05" />
```

Comment: In my script above, you have for example "formObject.firmenp". How can I add in your recommendation? and maybe we can continue the conversation in chat? Thank you so much :)

Comment: If you could post your form with minimal input that would be great, like just with one input in a form and the function you are calling from

Comment: The original apps script is available here [link] (https://script.google.com/home/projects/1VXgcXJA0joQ0YYi3_w-UwUnpgiHA2KlayxqCf7uswk_vzS74uwTI4njD/edit). And the original google sheet is available here [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18IouL2TKOgJ84QuB2s1tfrzsbUAGL-kucSPMugv9SdQ/edit#gid=0). You will need to make copies of them. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: @BobHardball see I have made an example [here](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1EM8RSakKWY8QG0IXEJBvOn5Lh7AWF6ibpC8yZ1isfiwOwoIU8QXR9ddx/edit). check code.gs is like 48 and below.

Comment: Just clicked on the link and asked for access. Can you let me in and have access to it? Thanks :)

Comment: I did, sorry my mistake, check again please

Comment: @BobHardball also check this [link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/62586/how-to-format-the-date-in-this-google-apps-script), hope it can help

Comment: When I add and try the modification you recommended on the link, I get this result in my google sheet "NaN/NaN/NaN". Are you getting the same result on your end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238797/discussion-between-tba-and-bob-hardball).

Comment: One more thing: In your modification, you have the function getNewDateFormat("2021-11-05"). Is that normal? I mean I need my dates in format DAY/MONTH/YEAR.

Comment: The script is now working perfectly fine. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!